# Least square function is coercive if and only if matrix is injective

Tags: optimization, least-squares, coercive

Let $\phi \in \mathcal{M}_{M,N}(\mathbb{R})$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^M$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}||\phi x - y||^2$.
I want to show that $f$ is coercive if and only if $\phi$ is injective.

---

This is what I have done :

For the first direction. Suppose that $\phi$ is not injective so there exists $x_0 \neq 0$ such that $\phi(x_0)=0$. For all integers $n$ define $x_n = n \cdot x_0$.
We see that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty} ||x_n|| = +\infty$ whereas $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to +\infty} f(x_n) = \frac{1}{2}||y||^2$. Thus $f$ is not coercive.

For the other direction, i'm having some trouble. I noticed that
$$
\frac{1}{2}||\phi x - y||^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}(||\phi x|| - ||y||)^2
$$
If I show that $\displaystyle\lim_{||x|| \to +\infty} ||\phi x|| = +\infty$ I could conclude but I can't get any further.

---

Any comments are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: $A$ being injective means that $\sigma_{\min}(A) > 0$ (where $\sigma_{\min}$ denotes the smallest singular value). Therefore $\|Ax\| \geq c \| x\|$ for some $c > 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Injectivity of $\phi$ implies that
$$
\|\phi(x)\|\ge c\|x\|
$$
for some positive $c$. That forces the right hand side of your last inequality to diverge to $\infty$ as $\|x\|\to\infty$. Hence the left hand side diverges to infinity as well, and then
$$
\|\phi(x)\|\ge\|\phi(x)-y\|-\|y\|\to\infty.
$$